# Prisma - adding new object into existing array and sorting it afterwards

Tags: mongodb, prisma

I'm using Prisma in combination with MongoDB and this is how I currently update existing document:

```
await prisma.H2H.update({
  where: { id: existingH2HDocument.id },
  data: {
    matches: {
      push: {
        matchId: editInput.matchId,
        leagueId: editInput.leagueId,
        date: editInput.date,
        season: editInput.season,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Basically my model of the document looks like this:

```
id: 1234
matches: [
  {
    object1
  },
  {
    object2
  }
  ...
]
```

I'm adding new objects into the matches array, is there a way how to sort it during the update?

Using push adds them to the bottom but I need the newly added objects on the top(so basically an unshift).

Answer (score 0):

Thea easy solution to the at is to sort the data by whatever field you want in the query to get data, or just use an array method like array.prototype.reverse() whenever the data is recived by the client if you absolutely need it in that reversed order.

Or last option I can think of is to build in  nested resolver/mutation that triggers after the initial update is complete, where it gets the data, sorts it, and puts it back every time the object is updated.